# getting error while trying to input a search variable from database

Tags: r, error-handling, package

I'm trying to fetch data from my excel database, while doing so I'm getting the following error
Error in or("nno", "_CG") :
operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types

Following is the code I wrote

> tic3 <- capture("TIC" %R% one_or_more(DGT)) %R% one_or_more(DOT) %R% or("nno" , "_CG") %R% optional(DGT)

It fetches till this part of the code

> tic1 <- capture("TIC" %R% one_or_more(DGT)) %R% one_or_more(DOT)

I want to fetch data related to TIC and other added data input like the nos. associated with it

Comment: Hi Aliviya! Welcome to StackOverflow. A thing that would be really helpful in helping me answer your question is a [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)